# Proving a function of a bounded variation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For $a$, $b$ > 0, define the function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ by $f(x) = x^{a}\sin(1/x^{b})$ for $0 < x \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$. Show that if $a> b$, then $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0, 1]$, by showing that $f'$ is integrable over $[0, 1]$. Then show that if $a \leq b$, then $f$ is not of bounded variation on $[0, 1]$.

First, we see clearly that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$. Also, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=0=f(0).$ Moreover, $f$ is differentiable over $(a,b)$ with $f'=ax^{a-1}\sin(1/x^b)-bx^{a-(b+1)}\cos(1/x^b)$ on $(0,1)$, and we see that $f'$ is continuous on $(0,1]$. I can not see the continuity for $f$ at x=0 becouse when $1>a>0$ we have a problem.

Any thoughts or ideas about that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $f'$ is integrable; continuity at $0$ is not required. Can you verify that each of the two terms in $f'$ is intergrable? Once you do that use the fact that $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^{y} f'(t) \, dt$ to show that $f$ is of bounded variation. [Total variation of $f$ is less than or equal to $\int_0^{1}|f'(t)|\, dt$].

Comment: I could not veify that for the first term because of $a-1$ if its negative!!

Comment: @Ahmed $\sin (1/x^{b})$ is bounded. $x^{a-1}$ is integrable: $\int_0^{1}x^{a-1} \, dx=\frac 1 a x^{a}|_0^{1}=\frac 1 a$.

Comment: Yeah yeah I got it than you